# Configuring .ssh/config to forward host aliases to a remote host?

Tags: ssh, alias

We use `jump hosts` to access our hardware. These hosts are short-lived (less than a day), and are different every time they're generated. I would like to be able to configure my local `.ssh/config` file to have the `aliases` to my real hardware, and be able to forward those `aliases` to my `jump host`.

I had tried the following command but it failed:

```
ssh <jumphost> -t bash -ci ssh <hostalias>
```

Are there any options that I can try?

`jumphost` don't mind hand typing, because it is changes so frequently. I just would like a way to automate the process of jumping to that host, and then to the real hardware from there.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host farsidehost
    HostName acutalremotehostname.example.com
    ProxyJump bastionhost.example.com
```

You can then execute `ssh farsidehost`.

If as your updates tell, the name of the jumphost changes frequently, you can instead specify it on the commandline:

```
$ ssh -J jumphostoftheday.example.com actualremotehostname.example.com
```

If there is some way to procedurally find the name of the jumphost, this can be automated:

```
$ ssh -J $( determine_jump_host ) actualremotehostname.example.com
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I should make it more clear in my question; our jump hosts are different every time (they only live for a few hours at a time).

Comment: In that case you can on the command line specify the jump host:  `ssh -J jumphost.example.com farsidehost.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Use local variable names for the real hardware, and have your local ssh command line expand those variables.

```
proddb=dc1r12u10.internal.dns
jumper=vm20180913.internal.dns
ssh $jumper -t bash -ci ssh $proddb
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I made it more clear in my question just now, sorry; our jump hosts are different every time (they only live for a few hours at a time).